# Use Loops to print out text file to terminal

Tags: java, while-loop

I am able to print out the entire text file, but i want it to print the student name, total number of quizzes taken, and the average of the scores.
This is the output:

And the output:

```
Student Name         Number of Quizzes           Average
Kirk James Tiberius 95 86 87 92 95 93 91 94
Summers Buffy 76 57 98 92 91 83 85
Baker Tom 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
Reynolds Malcolm 82 81 83 85 84 86 88 76 93
Bennet Elizabeth 91 93 95 94 89 93 95 96 94
Blutarsky John 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
Gale Dorthy 86 75 91 88 88 87 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at studenttester.StudentTester.main(StudentTester.java:36)
Java Result: 1
```

This is my Code:

```
package studenttester;

public class Student {
    private String name;
    private double totalScore;
    private int numQuizzes;
    String grade;

    /**
     * Returns the name of a student
     *
     * @return the name of the student
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a quiz score to the total quiz score of the student
     *
     * @param score the score of a quiz
     */
    void addQuiz(int score) {
        numQuizzes += 1;
        totalScore += score;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the total score of all the quizzes combined that student took
     *
     * @return the value of score
     */
    double getTotalScore() {
        return totalScore;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the average score of all the quizzes a student took
     *
     * @return
     */
    double getAverageScore() {
        return totalScore / numQuizzes;
    }
}
```

```
package studenttester;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudentTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int digit = 0, amount = 0, quizzes = 0, sum = 0, next = 0;
        String name;
        boolean goodData = true;

        System.out.println("Student Name         Number of Quizzes           Average");

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File("quizScores.txt"));

        while (goodData) {
            name = reader.next();
            System.out.print(name);
            System.out.println(reader.nextLine());

            if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
                digit = reader.nextInt();
                sum = sum + digit;
                quizzes++;
            }
            sum = next;
            quizzes = next;
        }
        double quiz = 0;
        while (goodData) {
            name = reader.next();
            System.out.print(name);
            System.out.println(reader.nextLine());

            if (reader.hasNextInt()) {
                digit = reader.nextInt();
                sum = digit + sum;
                quizzes++;
                sum = next;
                quizzes = next;
            }
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(sum / quizzes);
        }
    }
}
```

I think I need loops to identify between an integer and a name, but unsure how to do so.

Comment: Did you have an example of the file data which would generate the error you're having?

Comment: Are there any code to set "goodData" to false? Otherwise, it will be infinite loops, and the scanner will soon have nothing to read from.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, the format looks lot more better.

Comment: Same thoughts as @MadProgrammer. 

I think a small sample of your input data will be helpful to the community because there might be an easier way to do this. For instance if it is a CSV file then we probably can use some libraries to get the job done cleanly.

Comment: It's just a file out of note pad that says :       Kirk James Tiberius 95 86 87 92 95 93 91 94 Summers Buffy 76 57 98 92 91 83 85 Baker Tom 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 Reynolds Malcolm 82 81 83 85 84 86 88 76 93 Bennet Elizabeth 91 93 95 94 89 93 95 96 94 Blutarsky John 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 Gale Dorthy 86 75 91 88 88 87                                                 -10